# react-script problem while having a node_module folder in the parent directory

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, react-scripts

I have another node_module folder in the parent folder of my project. I updated react-script to v2 and while I am trying to start the project I get an error like below:

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.19.1"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

  /parent_dir/node_modules/webpack (version: 4.20.2)
```

However, my project is in this directory and has its own node_module folder:

```
  /parent_dir/my_project/node_modules/webpack (version: 4.20.2)
```

Everything goes OK if I delete parent's node_modules!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got that This is intended. We can skip preflight checks using instructions provided at the documentation in the react-scripts repo to solve the problem. However, I still don't know what is the reason for this pre-flight check.

Comment: agreed, I don't understand why webpack being in a parent folder matters to react-scripts

Comment: @BenClayton from Dan Abramov: We often had bug reports where npm produced bad installs (eg when mixed with yarn) and that caused plugins to find wrong webpack and fail with VERY confusing errors.