# react-scripts parent folder node_modules error when running in child location

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules, create-react-app, babel-loader

When running react-scripts build `(Create-React-App)` in a sub folder `(c:\Repos\web_app1\api_ui)` with it's own `package.json`, `node_modules` folder, etc. I get the following error:

```
 react-scripts build


There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-loader": "8.0.4"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-loader was detected higher up in the tree:

  c:\Repos\web_app1\node_modules\babel-loader (version: 7.1.4)
```

- Updating the parent folder's `(c:\Repos\web_app1)` **babel-loader to v8.0.4** is not an option as `web_app1` depends on **babel-loader v7.1.4**
- Deleting the node_modules in c:\Repos\web_app1 is not an option. This is the parent application and needs its own `node_modules`.
- My fix was adding `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to and .env file. This seems like a hack and I would like another fix that involves building through the preflight check.
- The package-lock.json in the sub folder `(c:\Repos\web_app1\api_ui)` has the correct **babel-loader version (8.0.4)**, so why is it going to the parent folder?

Is there a way to ignore parent folder or higher tree `node_modules` when building react-scripts in a sub folder?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-script problem while having a node\_module folder in the parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282430/react-script-problem-while-having-a-node-module-folder-in-the-parent-directory)

Answer (score 1):

This puzzled me a lot too and I did some research, looking in to the source code of `react-scripts` version `4.0.3`. This version requires `babel-loader` v. `8.1.0`. With `storybook` installed (requiring version `^8.0.0`), we get a different `babel-loader` in the top level `node_modules` so that we end up with:

```
|-src
|-node_modules
  |
  |-storybook 6.3.12
  |-babel-loader 8.2.6
  |-react-scripts 4.0.3
    |
    |-node_modules
      |
      |-babel-loader 8.1.0
```

I get the same error message as a lot of people have seen, and I think to myself, shouldn't any use of `babel-loader` in `react-scripts` get the `babel-loader` in its own `node_modules`, namely version `8.1.0`? I can delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` any number of times and it seems the problem always persists.

How you describe it in the question is in fact how the package managers (at least `npm`) works, e.g. importing `babel-loader` from `react-scripts` WOULD give it version `8.1.0` from its own `node_modules`... but we forget about two things, that combined will cause problems:

- Package hoisting
- Transitive dependencies

### Package hoisting

I won't go into details on when package hoisting occurs, but it happens. Basically, it amounts to a dependency package `B` of a dependency `A` being added to the project root `node_modules` (or some other parent `node_modules`) instead of to the `node_modules` of `A`.

So instead of

```
|-src
|-node_modules
  |
  |-A
    |
    |-node_modules
      |
      |-B
```

... we get ...

```
|-src
|-node_modules
  |
  |-A
    |
    |-node_modules (might exist anyway)
  |-B
```

Due to how `npm` works (and as you correctly understood it in the question), if `B` cannot be found in `node_modules/A/node_modules`, it will look in `node_modules` for the package, which makes this work. Hoisting can be an optimization when many packages all need compatible dependencies so that we, instead of storing N similar versions of the dependency, can store only one. It also simplifies the folder structure of the project root `node_modules` which is then easier to debug. As a matter of fact, the default is to hoist any packages that can be hoisted, e.g. that don't already exist in the `node_modules` to hoist to.

Usually, fallback to the naive strategy, with "all dependencies for a package in its own `node_modules`", is used whenever we have conflicting package versions. This is what has happened in the top example with two different versions of `babel-loader`; `storybook` really consists of several packages and multiple of them uses `babel-loader` version `^8.0.0`. When `storybook` is installed before `react-scripts`, it takes the most recent version of `babel-loader` which meets the constraint, and it hoists it to the top-level `node_modules`. This then causes the familiar problems when `react-scripts` is installed. I have another project with the same setup, but where `react-scripts` was installed before `storybook`. There, `babel-loader` version `8.1.0` is hoisted instead, and since this package also meets the requirements of `storybook` (`^8.0.0`), no more `babel-loader`'s are needed. Here, `create-react-scripts` does not complain. It is of course desirable that `npm` could figure this order out by itself, which is also optimal from a storage perspective (only one `babel-loader` instead of two), but as far as I know, `npm` uses alphabetical order when processing dependencies.

### Transitive dependencies

Even though package `A` is a dependency of my project, `A` can have dependencies of its own. These are transitive dependencies with respect to my project.

### Why doesn't it work?

In the source for `react-script` version `4.0.3`, the file `verifyPackageTree` is responsible for running the check hat results in the boring error message in the question. This file is no longer around in later prereleases, but in it at the top, we find the comment:

```
// We assume that having wrong versions of these
// in the tree will likely break your setup. 
// This is a relatively low-effort way to find common issues.
```

A few rows down it says:

```
// These are packages most likely to break in practice.
// See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1795 for reasons why.
// I have not included Babel here because plugins typically don't import Babel (so it's not affected).
```

Looking at the referenced thread, there is a discussion about why `create-react-app` breaks when non-compatible dependencies are installed with the same question as above... **WHY** doesn't it work?

The final conclusion seems to be that if, for example, `react-scripts` imports a package `X` that has been hoisted, this package won't reside in the `node_modules` under `react-scripts` but instead in the root `node_modules`, where (with respect to the topmost example) also `babel-loader` version `8.2.6` resides (as opposed to version `8.1.0` in the `node_modules` folder of `react-scripts`). Now if `X` were to import `babel-loader`, it would get the wrong `babel-loader`, e.g. NOT version `8.1.0` as expected but instead `8.2.6`. In the thread this is considered a bug in `npm` even though I don't exactly know why it would be a bug. Perhaps, there could be some flag indicating whether it is ok to hoist a package or not because if hoisting altogether is considered a bug, it seems like as step backwards.

Because the writers of `create-react-app` can't know whether some dependency is hoisted or not, they have implemented this simple check which throws a warning. For advanced users they give a chance to opt out of the check with the `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK` flag. Also, it is good to remember that the error comes from `create-react-app`, not `npm`, so it really doesn't say anything about how `npm` works, only what the creators of `create-react-app` considers a problem (which was indeed equally confusing initially).